# How to hide label of html input element

Tags: html, jinja2

I am trying to hide the label of an input element in html.

```
<input type="hidden" id="filex" name="filex" style="background-color:white">{{edit_card.id}}</input>
```

I am trying to hide the value of `{{edit_card.id}}` from displaying.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .html add:
`style="display: none;"`

or add html tag :

`<label hidden>{{edit_card.id}}</label>`

or in .css file add style for element with id='fillex':
`#fillex {display:none;}`

{{edit_card.id}} will be invisible for user but accessible by Right Mouse Click - inspect from browser.

Comment: This does not work but thanks!

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="filex" name="filex" style="background-color:white;"><label hidden>{{edit_card.id}}</label></input>

Comment: mplungjan if you are so concerned I would suggest you go ahead and do it yourself